# Running latex codebox in CherryTree

Tags: math-mode

I've inserted a codebox in CherryTree and set it to Latex language. I want to run a little snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\int f(x)$

\end{document}
```

in that codebox.
If I execute it, then my xterm says

> Output written on exec_code.dvi (1 page, 324 bytes). 
>   Transcript written on exec_code.log

No idea what that means. Why doesn't my executed latex code show up?

Comment: It means that your LaTeX code has succesfully been compiled and the result has been written to a file, in this case a `.dvi` file which is an intermediate file format that can be converted further to a pdf file (and a few other file formats). From a quick look at the CherryTree documentation it seems that this is indeed the expected behavior, and there is no functionality to actually display the result. There is a feature request for this: https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree/issues/178 but it's over four years old, still open and without any activity since 2017.

Comment: @Marijn thank you! Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install xterm then a window will appear when you execute a code.

sudo apt install xterm

This can be controled in preferences dialog.

[image: preferences dialog]